# Solve an inequality $|x| + |x-y| \geq |x_0| + |x_0-y| $ for $y$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, inequality, arithmetic

> Fix $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$. Describe $y \in \mathbb R^n$ that satisfies $|x| + |x-y| \geq |x_0| + |x_0-y|$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

I have tried triangle inequalities (including reverse) repeatedly, but does not seem to work. How can I describe such $y$?

Comment: @dxiv My bad, I have changed notation in the middle from $z$ to $y$. It should now display the equations correctly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Ok that's better. hint: did you know that $|a-b|=|b-a|$? Also, what is the reverse triangle inequality?

Comment: @Sentinel135 Do you mean $|x-y| \geq |x| -|y|$ by reverse triangle inequality? I can see that $|x-y| \geq |x| - |y|$ as $|x| = |x-y + y| \leq |x-y| + |y|$, but not sure how I can exploit it.

Comment: Actually it's the other one. $|x_0|+|x_0-y|=|x_0|+|y-x_0|\geq |y| +|x_0|-|x_0|=|y|$

Comment: @Sentinel135 Thanks for the reply. But it seems like the RHS of the final inequality $|y| \leq |x_0| + |x_0-y|$ still depends on $y$ though..

Comment: Aren't you trying to find things about $y\in \mathbb R^n$ that will help you describe $y$? Also that's only half of the picture. Is there some relation that $|x_0|+|x_0-y|$ has that we have yet to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x_0=0$, clearly the inequality is satisfied by every vector $y$. Suppose $x_0\ne0$. If the given condition holds, in particular it must hold for $x=0$. Hence
\begin{align*}
|y| = |0| + |0-y| \geq |x_0| + |x_0-y|\ge|y|.
\end{align*}
Therefore, equality holds in the triangle inequality $|x_0|+|y-x_0|\ge|y|$, meaning that $y-x_0$ is a nonnegative multiple of $x_0$. So we conclude that $y=kx_0$ for some $k\ge1$.

It remains to verify that the original inequality indeed holds when $y=kx_0$ for some $k\ge1$. I will leave it to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it seems like I don't quite get why $y-x_0$ is a nonnegative multiple of $x_0$ from the above inequality..:(

Comment: @Urvine One may prove the triangle inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. So, if equality holds, one vector must be a scalar multiple of the other. However, if $v\ne0$ and $\|cv+v\|=\|cv\|+\|v\|$, then $|c+1|=|c|+1$ and hence $c\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

Geometric consideration shows that $y$ and $x_0$ are **co-linear** and for this purpose, analytically, let $x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda)x_0$ for $\lambda>0$ then
$$|\lambda y+(1-\lambda)x_0| + |\lambda y+(1-\lambda)x_0-y| \geq |x_0| + |x_0-y|$$
$$|\lambda y+(1-\lambda)x_0| + (1-\lambda)|x_0-y| \geq |x_0| + |x_0-y|$$
$$|x_0-\lambda(x_0-y)|  \geq |x_0| + \lambda|x_0-y|$$
this inequality valid only if $\lambda(x_0-y)=k x_0$, for a real $k$.